# jQuery UI Sortable not working with bootstrap modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I want to use jQuery Sortable with bootstrap modal box. I have included all the files but its not working at all. Without modal box its working fine. Here is my sample code

```
<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="sortable-wrap">
          <ul id="sortable">
              <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
              <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
              <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
              <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
              <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
              <li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
              <li class="ui-state-default">Item 7</li>
          </ul>
      </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS code looks like this

```
jQuery( "#sortable" ).sortable();
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/ekrgho76/2/) if someone wants to check.

So can someone tell me why the sortable is not working here? How to make it workable here? Any suggestion or advise will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: are you just trying in fiddle or did u try on ur local.

Comment: I have first tried on my localhost. Its not worked that's why I have done the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your code works fine. Just check JQuery UI 1.9.2 to import the library.
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ekrgho76/3/)

Comment: @Codeone I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980128/how-to-sort-bootstrap-modal-body-elements-in-javascript-jquery). I am wondering if you can give me pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your code doesnt have any issue. But I would recommend if you do something like this.

```
$("#myModal").on("shown",function(){
  $( "#myModal #sortable" ).sortable();
})
```

And plus import jQuery Ui in your fiddle.